# cannot for the life of me get $caseid to post

Tags: php, html, ajax

Good day

I have a form that gets the case id from previous post, i then do a select with it and all works 100%

I then let them fill in data and upload files. all good, everything posts as should expect the caseid!!!!

code below.

```
    <!---<input type="submit" value="Submit">-->
     <?php
require_once("../models/config.php");
if(isUserLoggedIn()) {
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
require_once("../models/header.php");
echo "<link href='../models/site-templates/default.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />";


//$servername = "***.****.***.***";
$servername = "***.****.***.***.****";
$username = "202";
$password = "202@202";
$dbname = "*********";
$caseid = $_REQUEST['caseid'];


echo "
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='top'><div id='logo'></div></div>
<div id='content'>
<h1>Cases</h1>
<div id='left-nav'>";

include("../left-nav.php");

echo "</div><div id='main'>";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "
SELECT
    id
    , case_number
    , date_entered
    , name
    , STATUS
    , description
    , cust_phone_no
    , claim_number_c
    , contactname_c
    , contact_type_c
    , telephonehome_c
    , telephonebusiness_c
    , telephonemobile_c
    , policynumber_c
    , billing_address_street
    , billing_address_city
    , billing_address_state
    , billing_address_postalcode
    , billing_address_country
    , customer_name
FROM
    *******.sp_case_view
where id = '$caseid'";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $caseid = $row["id"];
        $case_number = $row["case_number"];
    $date_entered = $row["date_entered"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $status = $row["STATUS"];
    $description = $row["description"];
    $cust_phone_no = $row["cust_phone_no"];
    $claim_number_c = $row["claim_number_c"];
    $contactname_c = $row["contactname_c"];
    $contact_type_c = $row["contact_type_c"];
    $telephonehome_c = $row["telephonehome_c"];
    $telephonebusiness_c = $row["telephonebusiness_c"];
    $telephonemobile_c = $row["telephonemobile_c"];
    $policynumber_c = $row["policynumber_c"];
     $billing_address_street = $row["billing_address_street"];
    $billing_address_city = $row["billing_address_city"];
    $billing_address_state = $row["billing_address_state"];
    $billing_address_postalcode = $row["billing_address_postalcode"];
    $billing_address_country = $row["billing_address_country"];
    $customer_name = $row["customer_name"];


echo "<a href='cases.php'><b>Back to Cases</b></a><br><br>";
echo "Customer Name: " . $customer_name ."<br>";
echo "<br>";
        echo "Case Number: " . $case_number ."<br>";
        echo "Created On: " . $date_entered ."<br>";
echo "<br>";
        echo "Description: " . $description ."<br>";
        echo "Phone Number: " . $cust_phone_no ."<br>";
        echo "Claim Number: " . $claim_number_c ."<br>";
        echo "Contact Person: " . $contactname_c ."<br>";echo "<br>";
        echo "Address Details: <br>";
        echo "Street: " . $billing_address_street ."<br>";
        echo "City: " . $billing_address_city ."<br>";
        echo "Province: " . $billing_address_state ."<br>";

        //echo "Name: <input type='text' value='" . $description . "'><br>";




    }


$up_id = uniqid();
require_once("../models/footer.php");
$conn->close();
}
else {
header('location: ../login.php');
}

       $full_path = "c:/scott/source/";


     $number_of_uploads = 4;


     $allowed_file_types =    array("jpg","gif","png","txt","zip","xls","doc","docx","xlsx","txt","pdf");


    $upload_folder = "./uploads/";

   $max_size_in_kb = 10000024;

   $rename_files = 1;
echo $caseid;
  function printForm()
    {


   global $allowed_file_types,$number_of_uploads,$max_size_in_kb;

   print "<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title></title>
<meta name='description' content='' />
<meta http-equiv='Language' content='en' />
<meta name='language' content='en' />
<!--Progress Bar and iframe Styling-->
</head>

<body>
<br><b>Enter your closure details</b>
<!--<form action='upload.php' method='post'> -->

<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post' name='upload-form' id='upload-form'>

<table>
<tr><td>Plumber Cost including vat: </td><td><input type='text' name='plumcost'></td></tr>

<tr><td>Enter description of work done: </td><td><input type='textarea' name='descrepair'></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Old Geyser Make: </td><td><input type='text' name='geyserold'> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Old Geyser Serial Number: </td><td><input type='text' name='geyseroldserial'> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>New Geyser Serial Number: </td><td><input type='text' name='geysernew'> </td>
</tr>
</table>

\n";

  for($i=0;$i<$number_of_uploads;$i++)
  {
      if($i == '0') {
          echo "Invoice";
      }
         elseif($i == '1') {
          echo "POD";
      }
             elseif($i == '2') {
          echo "Stocksheet";
      }
             elseif($i == '3') {
          echo "Pictures Zipped";
      }
  print "<p><input type=\"file\" name=\"file[]\" /></p>\n";
  }

 print "<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"upload\" value=\"1\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\" /></p>\n</form>\n";

   print "<p>Allowed file types: ." . implode($allowed_file_types, " ."). "</p>\n";
    }

    $fileNAMES = array();

      if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {
     for($i=0;$i<$number_of_uploads;$i++)
       {
       if(strlen($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) > 0)
     {
     $filearray = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
    $ext = end($filearray);

        if($rename_files == 1)
        {
         if($i==0)  
         {  
          $fileNAMES[$i] = $caseid."invoice";
         }
         if($i==1)  
         {  
          $fileNAMES[$i] = $caseid."stocksheet";
         }
         if($i==2)  
         {  
          $fileNAMES[$i] = $caseid."POD";
         }
         if($i==3)  
         {  
          $fileNAMES[$i] = $caseid."picture";
         }
        }
        else
        {
        $xperiods = str_replace("." . $ext, "", $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
        $fileNAMES[$i] = str_replace(".", "", $xperiods);
        }

        if(!in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed_file_types))
        {
        print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) ."<br />ERROR: File type not allowed.</p>\n";
        }
        elseif($_FILES['file']['size'][$i] > ($max_size_in_kb*1024))
        {
        print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) ."<br />ERROR: File size to large.</p>\n";
        }
        elseif(file_exists($upload_folder.$fileNAMES[$i] .".". $ext))
        {
        print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($fileNAMES[$i]) .".". $ext ."<br />ERROR: File already exists.</p>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_folder.$fileNAMES[$i] .".". $ext))
            {
            print "<p>UPLOADED: ". htmlspecialchars($fileNAMES[$i]) .".". $ext ."</p>\n";
            }
            else
            {
            print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) ."<br />ERROR: Undetermined.</p>\n";
            }
        }
    }
    }

  printForm();
   }
   else
    {
      printForm();
  }


  ?>
</form>



</div></body>
</html>
<?php } else {
    echo "0 results";
        echo $caseid;
} ?>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the error you're having is. Post the actual error.

Comment: You need to add a hidden field with the name set as caseid & the value set to $caseid.